# ImageIO - Is video get_reader() fork safe?

Tags: python-imageio

I'm using ImageIO's `get_reader()` function on a video in a context where the process doing this is going to be forked. This reader is then continually randomly indexed (using the `get_data` method). Eventually, I run into an error `imageio.core.format.CannotReadFrameError: Could not read frame -1`. If the process is not forked, this error doesn't occur. Is ImageIO's `get_reader()` not fork safe? Or does my problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: Could you post the code?